# open attribute is not working for sqlite3dbm

Tags: python, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, sqlite3-ruby, dbm

I have to develop dbm module using sqlite. Hence I have imported sqlite3dbm with open attribute to create the new database. But it is saying  "module 'sqlite3dbm' has no attribute 'open'". The code which i m trying to run is from internet. Is sqlite3dbm dependent on python version. I am using python3.6
Please help to resolve the issue.

```
import sqlite3dbm
#import sqlite3
b = sqlite3dbm.open('mydb.sqlite3', flag='c')
```